# What is the microcode scoreboard?

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, intel, intel-pmu, microcoding

I've noticed that some versions of the Intel PMU include a counter like `PARTIAL_RAT_STALLS.SCOREBOARD` on Cascade Lake that is documented as "This event counts cycles during which the microcode scoreboard stalls happen." I can't find any information online as to what the microcode scoreboard is. There's a similar counter in Ice Lake: `RESOURCE_STALLS.SCOREBOARD` documented as "Counts cycles where the pipeline is stalled due to serializing operations."

Both counters are used under Top-down Microarchitecture Analysis as the level 4 counter `Serializing_Operation` documented as "This metric represents fraction of cycles the CPU issue-pipeline was stalled due to serializing operations. Instructions like CPUID; WRMSR or LFENCE serialize the out-of-order execution which may limit performance."

I have seen this counter increment for other instructions that I wouldn't consider serializing such as rdtsc (of course rdtscp is serializing). I've seen it increment in a few other strange places as well but I don't have an easy way to measure where precisely.

Comment: Probably a derivation of [this patented work](https://patents.google.com/patent/US11829767B2/en). It should be a table-like structure to keep track of resources used by an issued uop (e.g. the physical registers assigned to it's inputs and output).

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks! That is a huge hint. It seems from that patent that the counter may also involve stalls due to data dependencies which could explain what I was seeing. I'll need to figure out how to properly test it to be sure.